# SQL join with aggregate function

Tags: sql, db2

I've been asked to start working more with data analysis and have ran into similar issues with SQL aggregate functions. Here's a very simplified dataset of sales transaction log and warehouse balance:

```
SALES
Item    Period
A        2019
A        2019
A        2018
B        2019

WAREHOUSE
Item     SerialN
A        111
A        123
A        222
C        321
```

I need to run SQL **COUNT** function on **SALES** table which is simple enough:

```
select count(a.Item), a.Item from SALES a
where a.period = 2019
group by a.Item
```

*I also need to add the **COUNT** of items in **WAREHOUSE** table* - also very straightforward on its own but not so much when trying to combine them into one query result.

```
select count(a.Item), a.Item, count(b.Item) from SALES a
left join WAREHOUSE b on a.Item = b.Item

where a.period = 2019
group by a.Item
```

The one above would mess up the result due to JOIN multiplying effect from WAREHOUSE table. What would be the best way to reach the result below? Is there a neat way to do this at all?

```
Item    count_period    current_warehouse
A            2                 3
B            1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to group and filter data from the first table and then join with second table. Like this:

```
select A.item, A.count_period, count(W.item) current_warehouse
from (select S.item, max(S.Period) Period, count(S.Period) count_period    
      from SALES S
      where S.Period = 2019
      group by S.item) A
left join WAREHOUSE W on A.Item = W.Item
group by A.item, A.count_period;
```

One more way is:

```
select A.item, A.count_period, B.current_warehouse from 
(select S.item, max(S.Period) Period, count(S.Period) count_period    
      from SALES S
      where S.Period = 2019
      group by S.item) A
left join       
(select W.item, count(W.item) current_warehouse
from WAREHOUSE W
group by W.item) B
on A.item = B.item
```

or

```
select A.item, max(A.count_period), count(W.item) current_warehouse
from (select S.item, max(S.Period) Period, count(S.Period) count_period    
      from SALES S
      where S.Period = 2019
      group by S.item) A
left join WAREHOUSE W on A.Item = W.Item
group by A.item;
```

Here you have a [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=681b1bdae7b8b9aca239acf7a1f521d9) where you can see all three are returning same data.

Comment: Thanks, but in theory - if the warehouse is missing an item X, will I also miss out on sales transaction data for this item?

Comment: @Joey112 do you see the result in my demo ? It is exactly as you have wanted. Please add new data to the question (data example with X you are talking about) so I can see what you want to get in that case.  Because I do not understand the question from your comment.

Comment: Bloody hell, it worked, thanks! Had some trouble implementing this to my data and query which were more complicated in production, but got it to present correct data. Have to dig deeper now to really understand it.

Comment: @Joey112 you are welcome. I am happy to help. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Consider joining two aggregate queries using [Common Table Expressions (CTE)](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_10.0.0/apsg/src/tpc/db2z_createcte.html):

```
WITH s_agg AS (
   select s.Item, count(s.Item) as sales_count 
   from SALES s
   where s.period = 2019
   group by s.Item
), 
   w_agg as (
   select w.Item, count(w.Item) as warehouse_count
   from WAREHOUSE w
   group by w.Item
)

SELECT s_agg.Item, 
       s_agg.sales_count,
       w_agg.warehouse_count
FROM s_agg
LEFT JOIN w_agg
  ON s_agg.Item = w_agg.Item
```

Comment: Have to say - although a little longer, as a beginner, I can read and follow this code better. Unfortunately I can't test it out since I'll get "Only SQL <SELECT> statements are allowed" error. Probably some restriction from my SQL server avoiding the WITH command

Comment: Hmmm...if using DB2, CTEs should absolutely be supported. Are you using a different IBM product like Netezza (only search return for your error message)? What specific error number is raised? Are you using this as part of a larger query? How are you calling this query? From programming language like Java or Python using ODBC?

Comment: Sorry for the very overdue answer. I'm not administrating the db, mostly just write queries. It was a stand-alone query and launching it to DB2 database through Excel data connection. The IBM application / ODBC driver I use for this is "IBM iAccess Client". And the connection type is set as "Limit to Read-Only (Select statements only)". Alternatives are "Use ODBC access mode"; "Use ODBC access mode, Call allowed" and "Limit to Read/Call (Select and Call statements allowed)".